# How to move forward and backward one screenful text a time with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux

I'm trying to implement the `less` command with Ruby.
I guess I could somehow get enough information about the current terminal to decide how many contents to print, but I have no idea how I could simulate the behaviour of `b`, which skip back one page.

Answer (score 0):

```
▶ $stdin.tty? && $stdin.winsize
#⇒ [
#  [0] 80,
#  [1] 157
# ]
```

[More info](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#class-IO-label-io-2Fconsole).